# How to get Parameters from postman to save values from Laravel into database

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman

I working on an App, and I am creating web services for the App in Laravel. The issue I am facing is that I am not able to get parameters in `request` in controller to save values in database.

Below is the code I am using to send state id's in the app:-

```
public function signup(Request $request, $state_id){

    $get_cities = DB::table('all_cities')->where('state_code',$state_id)->get();

        return response()->json(['data' => $get_cities]);


    return view('frontend.pmjkyppa.pmjkyppa_signup',compact('get_cities'));
}
```

Below is the route I am using to send in the url:-

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/pmjkyppa_signup/{state_id}','pmjkyppa\HomeController@signup');
```

From the above url, we are able to get cities according to selected state id in the App.

Now, the main issue arises when from the same url I want to save details in the databse from postman.

For this, the code I am using in controller:-

```
      public function save_user_details(Request $request){

        $data   = $request->all();

        if($request->isMethod('post')){

        $full_name = $data['full_name'];
        $mobile = $data['mob_num'];
        $pwd    = $data['password'];
        $age    = $data['age'];
        $state_id   = $data['state_id'];
        $city_id    = $data['city_id'];
        $post   = $data['post'];
        $created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if($data['full_name'] != '' && $data['mob_num'] != '' && $data['password'] != ''
            && $data['age'] != '' && $data['city'] != ''){

            DB::table('pmjkyppa_users')->insert([
            ['full_name' => $data['full_name'], 'mob_num' => $data['mob_num'], 
            'password' => md5($data['password']), 'age' => $data['age'], 'state_id' => 
             $data['state_id'], 
             'city_id' => $data['city_id'], 'post' => $data['post'], 'created_at' => $created_at, 
             'updated_at' => '']
        ]);
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Saved!']);
        }else{

            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Plese Fill in your details!']);
        }
     }
```

And the route Url for this is:-

Route::match(['post'],'/pmjkyppa_signup/{state_id}','pmjkyppa\HomeController@sav 
   e_user_details');

I am using the same URL, but different functions. How can I save data with the same url from postman?

Comment: Did you tried with `Content-Type: application/json` in postman?

Comment: @HarunRRayhan No, I didn't try. I think I am doing it in a wrong way, maybe in routes, I am using both "get" and "post" method. I don't know what to use in laravel routes when to fetch data from postman.

Comment: I would recommend you not to use GET for data saving routes. 

Did you try with the POST method on postman? 
What response do you get? What is the status code? 

By default, web routes expect csrf_token. Where did you add the route in web.php or api.php?

Comment: @HarunRRayhan I am using POST method on postman and I am adding routes in web.php i.e. Route::match(['get','post'],'/pmjkyppa_register','pmjkyppa\HomeController@save_user_details'); I am adding this in web.php.

Comment: what is the response data and response status do you get in postman?

Comment: @HarunRRayhan I am not getting response, just HTML of the page is showing up and in POSTMAN I am using x-www-form-urlencoded.