# How to get values from postman in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I want to get values from postman, all I am getting is empty response. 
I want to save values in database by getting all the values from postman. Postman settings are okay. There is problem with my code because I am not getting the values.
Following is the code I am using in controller:-

```
public function save_user_details(Request $request){

        $data = $request->all();

        //return $response = array('status'=>'true');

        if(!isset($data['full_name']) && empty('full_name')){
            $result['status']   =  false;
            $result['message']  =  "Full name is required";
        }else if(!isset($data['mob_num']) && empty($data['mob_num'])){
            $result['status']   =  false;
            $result['message']  =  "Mobile Number is required";
        }else if(!isset($data['password']) && empty($data['password'])){
            $result['status']   =  false;
            $result['message']  =  "total_cost is required";
        }else if(!isset($data['age']) && empty($data['age'])){
            $result['status']   =  false;
            $result['message']  =  "age is required";
        }else if(!isset($data['city_id']) && empty($data['city_id'])){
            $result['status']   =  false;
            $result['message']  =  "City is required";
        }else{

            $full_name      = $data['full_name'];
            $mobile_number  = $data['mob_num'];
            $password       = $data['password'];
            $age            = $data['age'];
            $state          = $data['state'];
            $city           = $data['city'];
            $post           = $data['post'];
            $created_at     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $country_code   = '91';

        if($full_name != '' && $mobile_number != '' && $password != ''
            && $age != '' && $city != ''){

            DB::table('pmjkyppa_users')->insert([
                ['full_name' => $full_name, 'mob_num' => $country_code.$mobile_number, 
                'password' => md5($data['password']), 'age' => $age, 'state' => $state, 'city' => $city, 
                'post' => $post, 'created_at' => $created_at, 'updated_at' => '']
            ]);
                $result['status']   =  true;
                $result['message']  =  "Saved!";

        }else{
                $result['status']   =  false;
                $result['message']  =  "Plese Fill in your details!";

        }
        }
        echo  json_encode($result);
}
```

And following is the route:-

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/pmjkyppa_register','pmjkyppa\HomeController@save_user_details');
```

Comment: could you return the request at the top of your method and check it out? add this line `return request()->all()`

Comment: @Joseph. When I return request()->all(); then empty array is showing up on web page like this [].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Parameters from postman to save values from Laravel into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424666/how-to-get-parameters-from-postman-to-save-values-from-laravel-into-database)

Comment: please don't duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424666/how-to-get-parameters-from-postman-to-save-values-from-laravel-into-database

Comment: @ChristopheHubert okay. I'll keep in mind.. Thanks

Comment: is the result appears in postman request or from browser?

Comment: @Joseph From Browser.

Comment: @kyle that is normal to get an empty array try it from **postman** and pass any dummy `attributes`

Comment: @Joseph Okay! On postman only HTML code is showing up when sending request and where to send dummy attributes. I did not get this point.

Comment: @kyle add in your headerssection in postman `Accept: application/json`

Comment: @Joseph I have done this. Nothing happened. Infact, I am not getting any values in ```request->all();``` and due this I am getting error undefined index.